# Python: generate base64 string of certain length by input parameter

Tags: python, hash, base64

I have input string parameter **id** that might be any length (in general it in range 4-10 symbols and there are a few millions of them). My requirement is to generate string based on that parameter (it should be the same string for the same **id**) which base64 decode representation has exactly 32 byte.
Here it is:

```
str = generate(id)
len(base64.b64decode(str)) == 32

def generate(id) = ???
```

So I guess **generate** has to return 64encoded value.

Any ideas? I use python 2.7.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If no 2 `id`s can generate the same result from `generate`, this is impossible.  (If that constraint does not hold, you can always return the same string, regardless of what `id` is.)

There is a limit to how many different strings have a base64 decoding of exactly 32 characters.  You have placed no limit on how many different values of `id` this function should work for.  Thus, there must be at least 2 `id`s that `generate` will return the same value for.

Comment: I can accept a small percent of collisions but in general result should be the same for equals ids

Comment: for equals ids only*

Comment: Your problem, as currently described, *by definition*, will have a very LARGE percentage of collisions (since you place NO constraints on the size of `id`).

Comment: I'm not sure I've got your point, I probably need to look into my solution deeply. I completely newbie in that.

Comment: btw what do you mean by "very LARGE percentage" ? How much that can be?

Comment: I updated question with some information about id constraints